# Are there alternatives to the Box-Tiao decomposition in identifying mean reverting portfolios?

Tags: time-series, arbitrage, mean-reversion

As documented in [this paper,](http://www.di.ens.fr/%7Easpremon/PDF/MeanRevVec.pdf)
(*Identifying Small Mean Reverting Portfolios*,
by Alexandre d’Aspremont, February 26, 2008)
Box-Tiao decomposition (a way to decompose multiple time series into components with different speeds of mean reversion) can be used to identify mean reverting portfolios.

Are there alternative methods?

Answer (score 0):

Hudson and Thames has published on this topic, e.g. https://hudsonthames.org/copula-for-pairs-trading-introduction/.

I have no affiliation with the firm.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another from the same party that looks relevant also.

https://hudsonthames.org/introduction-to-hedge-ratio-estimation-methods/